# Can't inject EntityManager via @PersistenceContext - NullPointerException

Tags: hibernate, jpa, persistence

I am trying to create a DataManager, that is used as a facade for my Beans.
Unfortunately I can't get the EntityManager to work. 
I am trying to inject it via @PersistenceContext, but when using the EntityManager I always get a NullPointerException.

```
@ApplicationScoped
public class DataManager {

  @PersistenceContext(unitName = "MSM")
  private EntityManager em;

  /*
   * Adds a new employee to the database.
   * @param employee - the employee object that will be added.
   * @return true if transaction was successful.
   */
  public boolean createEmployee(Employee employee){     
    try {
        if (employee != null) {
            if (em.createNamedQuery("Employee.findByMail").setParameter("mail",employee.getMail()).getResultList().isEmpty()) {
                em.persist(employee);
                return true;
            }
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } 
    return false;
  }

}
```

Comment: Are you sure that spring _recognize or scan_ your DataManager class ?

Comment: It probably does not, because I didn't know that I have to do that. How do I check that?

Comment: sorry for the late response, I recommend you to read this [small tutorial](http://websystique.com/spring/spring-4-hello-world-example-annotation-tutorial-full-example/), consider it just as a starting point